# zsh: parse error: condition expected: "$1"

Tags: zsh

I tried to write a script to compile java files with gentoos java-config but i ended up getting an error 
zsh: parse error: condition expected: "$1" Can anyone tell me what this means and why it gets reported at line 16 in the function.

```
function jComp() {

local java_mods = ""

if (( $# == 0)); then
  echo "using javac on .java in folder"
  `javac *.java`
  return 0

elif [[ "$1" == "-h" ]] || [[ "$1" == "--help" ]]; then
  echo "Usage: jComp [java modules] [file]"
  echo
  echo "Options:"
  echo "    -h,   This help message."
  echo "modules has to be in the (java-config -l) list" 
  echo
  echo "Report bugs to <tellone.diloom@gmail.com>."

  return 0
fi

if [[ "$(java-config -v)" == "" ]]; then
  echo "This script depends on java-config"
  return 1
elif [[ "$1" =="-d" ]] || [[ "$1" == "--default"]]; then
 `javac -cp .:$(java-config -p junit-4) *.java`
  if [[ $# == 2 ]]; then
    `javac -c .:$(java-config -p junit-4) "$2"`
     return 0
  fi
fi


while (( $# > 1 )); do
if [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
    java_mods="$java_mods $1"
    shift
    continue
fi
done

`javac -cp .:$(java-config $java_mods)`

return 0
}
```

Links and comment are welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like your code is trying to compare a string stored in argument $1 to the string -d but the comparison is missing a space after the double equal sign:

```
elif [[ "$1" =="-d" ]] || [[ "$1" == "--default"]]; then
               ^

elif [[ "$1" == "-d" ]] || [[ "$1" == "--default"]]; then
```

I haven't tried the code but, do try and let me know if it solved it !

Btw, it also looks like the second comparison will also fail because of a lack of space before the double square closing brackets:

```
elif [[ "$1" == "-d" ]] || [[ "$1" == "--default"]]; then
                                                 ^
elif [[ "$1" == "-d" ]] || [[ "$1" == "--default" ]]; then
```

Comment: Why does this not work (one bracket, one equals): `if ( $# = 0); then` or `if [ $# = 0]; then`. It complains: `condition expected: =`

Answer (score 1):

All your backticked commands look wrong. You want to run the commands, not interpret their *output* as a command to run, right? If so, remove all the backticks from the `javac` invocations.

Then there is a missing space in `[[ "$1" =="-d" ]]` to make the `==` a separate token (and another as pointed out by leroyse).